# replacing innerHTML using replace method along with regular expressions not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have this menu which is being generated from the back end. The script adds a ">>" to the current menu item like the one below.

```
<ul class="links">                      
    <li class="active"><a href="news-265.html" style="color: white;">News &amp; Views</a> » </li>
    <li><a href="facts-269.html">Quick Facts</a></li>
    <li><a href="media-releases-268.html">Media Releases</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery-270.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="social-media-271.html">Social Media Channels</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="contacts-272.html">Media Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried using JavaScript to replace the >> with an empty string using the replace method and a regular expression according to a tutorial i saw on [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/you-dont-know-anything-about-regular-expressions/)

This is my javascript function

```
 (function(){
  var elm = $('.active');  
  elm = elm[0].innerHTML;   
  elm.replace(/>>/,"");   
})();
```

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks. here is a link to my [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ipenARe/1/edit)

Comment: I thought that they were the same thing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ipenARe/8/edit

```
$(function(){
 var elm = $('.active'); 
 var txt=elm.html();
 elm.html(txt.replace(/»/,""));   
});
```

Using pure JS, http://jsbin.com/ipenARe/10/edit

```
 (function(){
       var elm =document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0]; 
       var txt=elm.innerHTML;
       elm.innerHTML=txt.replace(/»/,"");   
 })();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I didn't think about using the html() but is there a way to do it in pure Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** for your particular case, you want is keeping only the "" element, so you can do this:

```
var elm = $('.active').children("a");  
$('.active').html(elm);
```

Comment: Jquery is already used as `$(".active")`, that's why I also added this solution ;)

Comment: I answered too fast, text() won't work and will remove the link anyway ... :/ * editing again *

Comment: So is using innerHTML is a big NO for such operations?

Comment: I've tried using the text as well as the textContent operations but they don't seem to work.

Comment: I thing what you want is to replace the `<li>` content by only the `<a>` element.

Comment: I just want to remove the » element from the html

Answer (score 0):

Try the regular exp to exclude special characters including(>>)

```
yourText.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "");
```

**[Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2KRHh/27/)**